# Utop Does Not Respond

Tags: ocaml, utop

I downloaded Utop for Ocaml a couple of days ago and it was working fine. Today I was doing some work and I had a bunch of shells running utop at once (I don't see why this would be a problem, but I might as well include details), and I tried opening Utop in yet another shell and I got the following: 
[image]

I've completely exited out Terminal, uninstalled and reinstalled Utop, and still all I get is this...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out restarting my computer fixed it. Not sure why or what was wrong, though.